# Flutter: What does "Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@99177fa" means?

Tags: flutter, console, flutter-engine

I do see it on the console whenever my flutter app goes to the background. Hence, why I am wondering what the technical meaning is.

**Update**

Would also like to know about this - `Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@99177fa`

Thanks